# How to change the css of body:before to affect color stop in a linear gradient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors, gradient

I have a linear gradient at the bottom of the page, which is set by `body:before`.  Now I want that 75% color stop to change as I scroll down the page, so I have the js/jquery code below. I don't think `$("body:before")`works, so how can I fix that, so as I scroll down the color stop gradually goes up too?

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

body:before {
    content:'';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0,0,1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) 75%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%);
}
```

Here's the js code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        $("body:before").css({
          "background": "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0,0,1) 0%, rgba(30,30,30,1) " + (75 - $(window).scrollTop()/100) + "%, rgba(180,180,180,1) 100%);"
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot target pseudoelements using jQuery! My suggestion would be to make an element with your desired styling and position it `absolute` or `fixed` (depending on what you want to achieve) to the bottom of the body or a container element, which would have `position: relative`.

OR

Add a class to the `body` which alters the styling of your `:before`. That's probably the better shout in all honesty!

Comment: There are ways to target pseudo elements with Jquery... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Comment: Your solution sounds much nicer though.